# iDangerous swiper parameter change has no effect even with reInit()

Tags: jquery, swiper.js

I have a swiper where I want to be able to dynamically toggle the `progress` parameter (I am using the `swiper-smooth-progress` plugin).

I initialized the swiper like this:

```
var mySwiper = $('.swiper-container').swiper({
   progress: false;    //slides just slide horizontally
});
```

At this point, the swiper-smooth-progress plugin is not enabled, so the slides are sliding right to left. So far, so good.

But then, after changing the `progress` parameter with:

```
var newValue = true;
mySwiper.params.progress = newValue;
mySwiper.reInit();
```

The slides do not move with the new effect. I have verified that the `progress` is set with the new parameter by looking at `mySwiper.params.progress` and seeing that it's now `true`. So the question is: can the new progress effect be implemented dynamically, or do I need to destroy the slilder and create a new one with the new parameter?

Answer (score 1):

`reInit()` does not see the progress plugin.

When you set `progress = true` in the first instance, it all works fine but when you set it to false and reInit it will not initialise progress.

You can test this by setting it to true and then:

```
console.log(mySwiper.progress)
```

You will see the value of the current progress of the swiper.

If you set it to false and then try the same console log, you will not get a number.

There is some deep rooted issue with this plugin, it also doesn't listen for progress updates within itself. Maybe contact the creator

Comment: Correct. In order to do what I want, I ended up just removing all slides and re-adding them using the new progress settings. I am not sure how this will perform with a large image gallery...probably not well.

Comment: It may not take a heavy load, but if you just need it to handle a few, you may get away with it. Good luck!